# Work out height of heap from elements

Tags: algorithm, height, element, heapsort, heap-size

I am trying to work out the height of a heap given there are 210 elements.

I have tried using the log(n+1) -1 formula however I am getting a weird answer. I also tried drawing it the heap out and that way I get that it would be a height of 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"however I am getting a weird answer."_ What is the answer you're getting?

Comment: Maybe you are using log10 instead of log2 in your calculation?

Comment: well i do log(210 + 1) -1 which equals 3.32 I am pretty sure the height wouldn't be that.

Comment: but using log2 gets 6.7 seems more reasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İf your heap is binary, the formula is like that, otherwise you can look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9914/finding-the-height-of-a-d-ary-heap.

```
height = ⌈log(base2)(n+1)⌉-1

height = ⌈log(base2)(200+1)⌉-1

height = ⌈7,..⌉-1

height = 8-1

height = 7
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't log (base 2) (211) equal to 7.7 or can we just round up?

Comment: Yes, 7.7, so you should end up with height = 7.